# To send structure using TCP IP in qt

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, qtnetwork

I have following peice of code.  i am looking to send the Structure using TCP IP in qt, but i am not able to do it. Please help me to send the structure.

```
struct message
{
    U8 messagedata;
    U32 date;
}msg;
```

msg.messagedata = 30;

msg.date = 27;

then using write(msg, len(msg)) funtion to send. But how to put this Structure in this Write function. I am using built in Qt Network library for TCP/IP.

Answer (score 1):

For working with TCP in Qt you can use [QTcpSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html) and [QTcpServer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/search-results.html?q=qtcpserver) classes. `QTcpSocket` inherits [QIODevice](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html) class, which has method [write](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write) to write data in socket, as you need.

For sending you structure, you can pack you structure:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct message
{
    quint8  messagedata;
    quint32 date;
}msg;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

And then use write method, like this:

```
socket->write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(yourMessage), sizeof(msg));
```

Alternative way, you can implement operator for [QDataStream](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html):

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &stream, const msg &m)
{
  stream << m.messagedata;
  stream << m.date;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
QDataStream stream(socket);
stream << yourMessage;
```

Comment: What I have to put at yourMessage Variable?.

Comment: You can put your data in yourMessage. For example: msg yourMessage; yourMessage.messagedata = 30; yourMessage.date = 27; (as you want in question)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
QByteArray ba;
ba << msg.messagedata << msg.date;
socket.write (ba);
```

This just sends a `QByteArray` to the client, you need to send the size too (implement a simple protocol).